# Resque Mysql2::Error: User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, resque

I am running Resque on Heroku, and my database is ClearDB. I am getting this error:

"Mysql2::Error: User 'bdb2aedbee2c38' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10): SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `projects`"

That error is coming from my Resque admin of my Heroku app.

How can I figure out how many connections Resque is making to ClearDB?

How can I tell ClearDB to either allow more connections, or tell Resque to create less?

Does "current value: 10" refer to how many connections ClearDB is allowing, or is this how many current connections Resque is trying to make?

Thanks!

Comment: how many workers have your started and are running

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your application server dynos or Resque workers are consuming more connections than your database plan provides.

You have two options:

- Scale up your database by upgrading to a higher ClearDB plan (http://dashboard.heroku.com)
- Scale down your application by reducing the number of dynos/workers (`heroku ps:scale` command)

The first link when I googled your addons links to the page describing the service and pricing tiers.  You are on the free, 10 connection tier.

https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

Comment: how can i figure out how many connections my cleardb plan supports? where do i configure the db connections? i have one dyno. how would scaling down the workers help improve the max connections? also, how many jobs can i run before i hit max connections?

Comment: You can manage your plan addons through the link I provided you.