# "(User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10))" error on heroku

Tags: java, mysql, spring, heroku

This question is related to [Resque Mysql2::Error: User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937390/resque-mysql2error-user-has-exceeded-the-max-user-connections-resource-cur)

I'm receiving the error "(User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10))" when trying to insert a table into a MySql database.

I'm using this code to connect to the database :

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(password);

        return basicDataSource;
    }
}
```

whch is based on :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-database_url-in-plain-jdbc

To fix this issue can I re-use this connection ?

I've tried updating the code above to re-use the same BasicDataSource but I receive error.

When I check the client connections here is what I see :

[image]

The amount of client connection decreases over time, it seems there is max number of connection that can be made within a specified time span ?

Comment: Have you tried closing the connection?

Comment: @Dodd10x yes, ive tried closing the connection each time but same error

Comment: If you aren't using a connection pool, then its probably just the connections aren't being released properly. You may want to include your code showing how you create and release each connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I believe it is the database its self telling you that you have reached the limit. You can change it in the database options.

For a project I was working we used a connection pool and had a limit of 110 connections. This was based on a small size of users though.

Comment: Yeah, if it's mysql complaining about too many connections, then its possible that your pool size is too large for the mysql configuration. Some DB connection pool managers will keep giving out new connections even if they have idle ones until they reach the maxIdle parameter. Oracle UCP will elect the next connection to give out using round robin and only reduce the pool size if a connection is idle for longer than a specific timeout... which leads to situations where 1 thread that is constantly using and giving back connections can cause the pool to grow to its max idle size.