# Does the 'max_user_connections' resource error resolve if I change the server on Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my Rails (3.2.13) app on heroku (its almost 3 years for deployment). That time I have used unicorn as a server.

I have used ClearDB addon for setting mysql database on Heroku.

Currently I am facing issue where I am getting following error

```
Mysql2::Error (User 'username' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 54000)):
```

I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937390/resque-mysql2error-user-has-exceeded-the-max-user-connections-resource-cur) where he has suggested

- Scale up your database by upgrading to a higher ClearDB plan (http://dashboard.heroku.com)

  But I am already on the highest clearDB plan
- Scale down your application by reducing the number of dynos/workers (heroku ps:scale command)

  for this I have already reduced my worker dynos.

But Still facing the issue.

Can any one provide me other solution that would be great.

Should I move from unicorn to puma server?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the number of queries that are executed per hour as opposed to the number of connections as in the answer you've referenced (note the error is `has exceeded 'max_questions'` as opposed to `has excedded 'max_user_connections'`.

This answer https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/max-question-error-on-heroku and http://w2.cleardb.net/faqs/#multi_7 suggests that cleardb puts a limit on the number of queries that can be executed, which wouldn't be affected by the number of dyno's (assuming the same number of requests/workload will still be coming in), or changing from unicorn to puma.

I would suggest getting in touch with ClearDB support and seeing if they can put you on a plan that removes this restriction.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the MySQL variable `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` on `Heroku` for free accounts. Changing the number of connections at once requires upgrading the plan.
[Please refer to this link](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb)